# PLSQL procedure takes very long to execute

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have created the below procedure which ran just fine before I added the bold code. Now it's inserting 100 records at a time. It's been more than a hour and it has inserted only 4000 records. There are 2 million records to be inserted. Is there any way I can fasten the execution?

```
create or replace PROCEDURE LOAD_ADDRESS_PROCEDURE AS 

CNTY varchar2(100);

ST varchar2(100); 

createdby_value varchar2(50);

**defaultAddress_value varchar2(1);**

CURSOR C1 is 

SELECT ADDRESS, CITY, STATE, ZIP, COUNTRY, seasonal_start_day, seasonal_start_month, seasonal_end_day, seasonal_end_month, key_address_id, key_account_id, BAD_ADDRESS,
CREATED, CREATED_BY, address_type,

(select siebel_country_name from STATE_AND_COUNTRY_VALUES_LIST where s.COUNTRY IS NULL and s.state = siebel_state_abbreviation) newCNTY,

(select SF_COUNTRY_ABBREVIATION FROM STAGE_COUNTRY WHERE SIEBEL_COUNTRY = s.Country) newCountry,

(select SF_COUNTRY_ABBREVIATION FROM STAGE_COUNTRY 
WHERE SIEBEL_COUNTRY = (select siebel_country_name from STATE_AND_COUNTRY_VALUES_LIST where s.COUNTRY IS NULL and s.state = siebel_state_abbreviation)) newCountry1,

(SELECT SIEBEL_LOGIN from STAGE_USER where KEY_USER_ID = s.CREATED_BY) SiebelLogin,

(SELECT SALESFORCE_USER from STAGE_USER where KEY_USER_ID = s.CREATED_BY) SFUSER,

(SELECT KEY_USER_ID from STAGE_USER where KEY_USER_ID = s.CREATED_BY) KeyUserID,

**(SELECT KEY_PRIMARY_ADDRESS_ID FROM STAGE_ACCOUNT WHERE KEY_PRIMARY_ADDRESS_ID = s.KEY_ADDRESS_ID) defaultAddress**

FROM STAGE_ADDRESS s;

BEGIN

FOR i IN C1 LOOP

ST := i.state;

CNTY := i.country;

/*if(i.newCountry = i.newCNTY) then*/

/*if (i.country  is null) then

CNTY := i.newCountry1;

end if;

comment end*/

if (i.state = 'NA') then

ST := NULL;

end if;

/*end if;*/

/*

if(CNTY != i.newCountry) then

CNTY := i.newCountry;

end if;

if(i.newCountry is null) then

CNTY := NULL;

end if;

comment end*/

IF(CNTY IS NULL) THEN
    CNTY := i.newCountry1;
    ELSE
    CNTY := i.newCountry;
END IF;

IF(i.CREATED_BY = i.KeyUserID AND i.SFUSER = 'MIGRATIONUSER') THEN
createdby_value := 'MIGRATIONUSER';
ELSE
createdby_value := i.KeyUserID;
END IF;

**IF(i.defaultAddress IS NOT NULL) THEN
defaultAddress_value := 'Y';
ELSE
defaultAddress_value := 'N';
END IF;**

INSERT INTO LOAD_ADDRESS(NPSP__MAILINGSTREET__C, NPSP__MAILINGCITY__C, NPSP__MAILINGSTATE__C, NPSP__MAILINGPOSTALCODE__C, NPSP__MAILINGCOUNTRY__C, NPSP__SEASONAL_START_DAY__C,
NPSP__SEASONAL_START_MONTH__C, NPSP__SEASONAL_END_DAY__C, NPSP__SEASONAL_END_MONTH__C, ERP_EXTERNAL_ID_C, NPSP__HOUSEHOLD_ACCOUNT__C, ADDRESS_STATUS_OVERRIDE, CREATED, 
CREATED_BY, NPSP_ADDRESS_TYPE_C, **NPSP__DEFAULT_ADDRESS__C**) VALUES 
(i.ADDRESS, REGEXP_REPLACE(i.CITY, '|||||', ' '), ST, i.ZIP, CNTY, i.seasonal_start_day, i.seasonal_start_month, i.seasonal_end_day, i.seasonal_end_month, i.key_address_id, i.key_account_id, 
DECODE(i.BAD_ADDRESS,'Y','1','N','0'), i.CREATED, createdby_value, i.address_type, **defaultAddress_value**);

COMMIT;

END LOOP;

END LOAD_ADDRESS_PROCEDURE;
```

Comment: How many records are present in table ```STAGE_ACCOUNT``` ? Is any type of index built on it?

Comment: Why you not replace this procedure with one `insert into ... (select ..)`?

Comment: Your code is a typical example of [slow-by-slow](https://asktom.oracle.com/Misc/slow-by-slow.html).

Comment: @SandeshGupta around 2 million...

Comment: @VasylMoskalov There is lot of data transformation involved.

Comment: did you try to debug it? how about removing the insert statement and commit inside the LOOP? Is it still long running? how about running the query in cursor alone, does it take long to query all the records? try to find first the part that making your procedure runs long

Comment: Your select is very ugly and bad. I **never** used expression like `SELECT ..., (SELECT ... FROM ...), ... FROM ...` and have written thousands of select statements in my life. Use `JOIN`, most likely `OUTER JOIN`. I did not check the logic in detail but I assume it can be done **without any loop** in a single `INSERT INTO LOAD_ADDRESS (...) SELECT ... ` - maybe two at maximum.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit really? You've never used scalar subqueries before? There is nothing ugly about them; in fact, they can (under certain circumstances) aid performance, due to scalar subquery caching, making them an excellent tool to stash in your SQL toolbox!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could rewrite your procedure to do all the logic in a single insert statement, something like:

```
INSERT INTO load_address
  (npsp__mailingstreet__c,
   npsp__mailingcity__c,
   npsp__mailingstate__c,
   npsp__mailingpostalcode__c,
   npsp__mailingcountry__c,
   npsp__seasonal_start_day__c,
   npsp__seasonal_start_month__c,
   npsp__seasonal_end_day__c,
   npsp__seasonal_end_month__c,
   erp_external_id_c,
   npsp__household_account__c,
   address_status_override,
   created,
   created_by,
   npsp_address_type_c,
   npsp__default_address__c)
  SELECT address,
         regexp_replace(i.city, '|||||', ' '),
         CASE
           WHEN state = 'NA' THEN
            NULL
           ELSE
             state
         END state,
         zip,
         CASE
           WHEN country IS NULL THEN
            newcountry1
           ELSE
            newcountry
         END country,
         seasonal_start_day,
         seasonal_start_month,
         seasonal_end_day,
         seasonal_end_month,
         key_address_id,
         key_account_id,
         DECODE(bad_address, 'Y', '1', 'N', '0'),
         created,
         CASE
           WHEN created_by = keyuserid
                AND sfuser = 'MIGRATIONUSER' THEN
            sfuser
           ELSE
            keyuserid
         END createdby_value,
         address_type,
         CASE
           WHEN default_address IS NOT NULL THEN
            'Y'
           ELSE
            'N'
         END defaultaddress_value
  FROM   (SELECT address,
                 city,
                 state,
                 zip,
                 country,
                 seasonal_start_day,
                 seasonal_start_month,
                 seasonal_end_day,
                 seasonal_end_month,
                 key_address_id,
                 key_account_id,
                 bad_address,
                 created,
                 created_by,
                 address_type,

                 (SELECT siebel_country_name
                  FROM   state_and_country_values_list
                  WHERE  s.country IS NULL
                  AND    s.state = siebel_state_abbreviation) newcnty,

                 (SELECT sf_country_abbreviation
                  FROM   stage_country
                  WHERE  siebel_country = s.country) newcountry,

                 (SELECT sf_country_abbreviation
                  FROM   stage_country
                  WHERE  siebel_country = (SELECT siebel_country_name
                                           FROM   state_and_country_values_list
                                           WHERE  s.country IS NULL
                                           AND    s.state = siebel_state_abbreviation)) newcountry1,

                 su.siebel_login siebellogin,
                 su.salesforce_user sfuser,
                 su.key_user_id keyuserid,

                 (SELECT key_primary_address_id
                  FROM   stage_account
                  WHERE  key_primary_address_id = s.key_address_id) defaultaddress
          FROM   stage_address s
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN stage_user su ON s.created_by = su.key_user_id);
```

I have moved your scalar subqueries on status_user to an outer join, since joining is likely to be more efficient than querying the same table 3 times. You could probably do something similar with the other scalar subqueries (i.e. combining them into a couple of joins or something) but I've left that for you to play with.

Comment: N.B. I left in some of the queries and columns that appeared to be unused in your procedure, just in case you did need them in your real-world code. However, if your code doesn't need them (e.g. in your original procedure, the `newcnty` column is not referenced anywhere outside of the cursor. Oracle will most likely filter that out of your insert-as-select statement, but if I were you, I would remove any unnecessary subqueries; that way you know your query is definitely not doing unnecessary work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to completely rewrite SELECT. You should probably use **joins** with STAGE_USER, STAGE_COUNTRY and any other table(s) that query uses.

There are some IFs which could be (at least, I hope so) rewritten by using CASE (or DECODE), which would make it possible to use *fast* SQL (a direct INSERT INTO) instead of *slow* PL/SQL (in a loop).

BTW, you're committing within the loop - remove COMMIT outside.